Failed to login 'username': AsyncClient.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxy'
Well, I was using the twscrape library in a virtual environment (venv) within PyCharm. At first, it worked perfectly a couple of times, but then it started to give the same error message, even though I didn't change any of the code. It mentions something about a proxy argument, but I'm not sure why.
import asyncio
from twscrape import API
from twscrape.logger import set_log_level


async def main():
    api = API()
    await api.pool.add_account('username', 'user_pass', 'email','email_pass')
    await api.pool.login_all()

    async for tweet in api.search("BTC"):
        print(tweet.id, tweet.user.username, tweet.rawContent)
    set_log_level("DEBUG")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

messege errors
2024-05-03 19:10:24.384 | INFO     | twscrape.db:migrate:96 - Running migration to v1
2024-05-03 19:10:24.429 | INFO     | twscrape.db:migrate:96 - Running migration to v2
2024-05-03 19:10:24.505 | INFO     | twscrape.db:migrate:96 - Running migration to v3
2024-05-03 19:10:24.555 | INFO     | twscrape.db:migrate:96 - Running migration to v4
2024-05-03 19:10:24.695 | INFO     | twscrape.accounts_pool:add_account:110 - Account <username> added successfully (active=False)
2024-05-03 19:10:24.704 | INFO     | twscrape.accounts_pool:login_all:183 - [1/1] Logging in njex_zzz211 - razzrrt211@gmail.com
2024-05-03 19:10:42.962 | ERROR    | twscrape.accounts_pool:login:165 - Failed to login 'username': AsyncClient.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxy'
2024-05-03 19:10:43.029 | WARNING  | twscrape.accounts_pool:get_for_queue_or_wait:297 - No active accounts. Stopping...
2024-05-03 19:10:43.045 | WARNING  | twscrape.accounts_pool:get_for_queue_or_wait:297 - No active accounts. Stopping...


maybe they changed something on web server and now it needs changes in module twscrape. Maybe there is newer version and you have to update module - using option -U or --update in pip install -U twscrape. And maybe you should check repo for twscrape - maybe someone else had similar problem with code. ie, Proxy issue · Issue #176 · vladkens/twscrape

Downgrade httpx works for me
httpx==0.27.2
